# How to Make Spark Streaming save file only when data is received?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am developing a very simple spark streaming application which takes inputTextFiles from an s3 location and does some transformations and again outputs the result to some s3 location.
but problem is

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> pairs = lines.mapToPair(
            line -> new Tuple2<String, String>(line, fetcher.fetchAndSaveUrl(process(line) ))
            );
pairs.dstream().saveAsTextFiles(s3Path + "/output", "output");
```

if saves file event if not processing has been done in particular batch interval with empty file called _SUCCESS.
how to make sure that it saves file only when some input has been read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter our empty RDDs (ie to check rdd.count() or rdd,isEmpty(), whatever you will find more suitable).
To achieve that you need to rewrite manipulation over DStream in a manner of using foreachRDD().